# Docker container fills out my disk

Tags: python, docker, celery, blender

### Configuration

- Debian Stretch
- Docker Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
- Docker Storage Driver: overlay2

  - Backing Filesystem: extfs
  - Supports d_type: true
  - Native Overlay Diff: true

### Issue

I am running a long-running docker task. When running it for a few hours I cannot see the container grow anything out of the ordinary, uses around 10-50 MB.
But when I leave it running over night I get back and have no more storage space on my docker partition.

When starting the container I am using 23 GB / 77 GB on my partition, when I get back after a night of running I always use 100%, even if the sizes of `docker system df` does not add up to more than the initial 23 GB.

All other running containers and functions are restored when I stop my specific container.

Why would the container size grow so fast? I have tried using `docker diff` on the container and checked the file sizes inside the container without finding anything specific.

Helpful for any clues.

#### Docker image

- Based on [`nvidia/cuda:9.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04`](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/)
- Installs `python3.6` and compiles [`Blender`](https://www.blender.org/) as a [python module](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule)
- The failing container is a [`Celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) worker which loads up Blender in python, creates a character and renders images of it.

#### Notes

- When I used `overlay` all running containers showed a size of `-1 B` when the disk got full.
- When the docker partition is filling up, my logs in `/var/log/` also grows, mostly errors of `no disk space`.

Comment: Any clue on what the container actually does? Can you provide the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @tgogos I added description about the Docker image, think this description might be easier than the Dockerfiles.

Comment: Ok, I would propose to also add the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` of the failing container. It would also be useful to add more tags to your question, so that people who "follow" these tags can share their knowledge. For example `blender`, `celery`...

Comment: @tgogos I just found a docker-log-file in the`/var/lib/docker/containers/...` of the failing container. This log file was 11 GB after 50 minutes. There was apparently a lot of outputs in my scripts that I did not know that docker logged. Hopefully it will work by running the container with `--logdriver none`.

Thanks for you help!